# How to loop more than 9 times in assembly language and how do you compare two 2 digit numbers in assembly?

Tags: loops, assembly, compare

I'm trying to run a loop that can loop up to 99 times, but when I try to loop more than 9 times it will not loop to the appropriate number. In this case of my code I want it to loop 20 times, but if I try to loop for more than 9 times it will be a infinite loop. How do I fix this? I know why it's printing the ascii after 9, but that is not my concern. Also how would I compare a variable of 2 bytes with another variable of two bytes? For example, if I have size1 with 05 in it how would I increment size2 so that it would equal 05 as I have tried to increment it but it only affects the value in the tens digit so it makes it 50 instead of 05. Thanks for the help.

```
section .data


star: db '*', 1
starLen1:  equ $-star  

shapename1:     db 'Rectangle',10    ;hold name output
shapenameLen1:  equ $-shapename1

shapename2:     db 'Triangle',10    ;hold name output
shapenameLen2:  equ $-shapename2

shapename3:     db 'Diamond',10    ;hold name output
shapenameLen3:  equ $-shapename3

counter1: dw 0x0000
counter2: dw 0x0000 

newline: db 0x0a



section .bss


choosenshape resb 1    ;holds shape user wants to draw

size1 dw 0x0000         ;holds the parameter for the size of the shape

size2 dw 0x0000         ;holds the widith for the rectangle

spacebewteenvalues resb 1 ;take space bwteen values


section .text
global _start

_start:

;loops for user input
shapesloop:

;set counter to 0
mov word [counter1], 0x0000

;get first value
mov ecx,choosenshape 
mov edx,1
call readthevalue

;end the program when equals period
cmp byte [choosenshape],  '.'
je end

;go to rectangle function if R
cmp byte [choosenshape],  'R'
je DrawtheRectangle

;go to Diamond function if D
cmp byte [choosenshape],  'D'
je DrawTheDiamond

;go to Triangle function if T
cmp byte [choosenshape],  'T'
je DrawtheTriangle

;keep looping until period is read
jmp shapesloop


;function to draw rectnagle
DrawtheRectangle:

;take space between 
call takespaces

;store amount of rows for rectangle
mov ecx,size1 
mov edx,2
call readthevalue

;take space between 
call takespaces

;store amount of rows for rectangle
mov ecx,size2 
mov edx,2
call readthevalue

;Display rectangle name
mov eax,4            
mov ebx,1            
mov ecx,shapename1      
mov edx,shapenameLen1     
int 80h     

OutputRectangle
mov word [counter1], 0 ; reset counter

.loop1:
mov word [counter2], 0 ; start loop and reset counter
mov ax, word [size1] 
cmp word [counter1], ax ; check if we are at the end of loop
jge endRectangle ; if we are end the function

.loop2:
mov ax, word[size2]
cmp word [counter2], ax ; start the second loop
jge .loop2end

mov eax, 4 ; write
mov ecx, star ; star's address
mov ebx, 1 ; to stdout
mov edx, 1 ; msg length is 1
int 0x80 ; write

add word [counter2], 1 ; add row count
jmp .loop2 ; loop

.loop2end:

mov eax, 4 ; write
mov ecx, newline ; newline's address
mov ebx, 1 ; to stdout
mov edx, 1 ; msg length is 1
int 0x80 ; write

add word [counter1], 1 ; add column count
jmp .loop1 ; loop

endRectangle:
ret ; or do something else


  
DrawTheDiamond:


DrawtheTriangle:







end:
mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
int 80h;




;FUNCTIONS






;reads the values from user input
readthevalue:    
mov eax,3        
mov ebx,0         
int 80h              
ret            ;return back 

;takes space between user input
takespaces:
mov eax,3            
mov ebx,0            
mov ecx,spacebewteenvalues      
mov edx,1     
int 80h 
ret            ;return back 




Printstar:
mov eax,4           
mov ebx,1          
mov ecx,star      
mov edx,1     
int 80h 
ret            ;return back
```

Comment: Try to tease apart the concepts of printable digits from numbers.  In most texts/codes, we differentiate between '0' and 0 -- the former, '0' means the digit '0' in an encoding scheme like ascii or unicode, where '0' has the numeric value 48!  The latter, 0, literally means the number 0.

Comment: Printable numbers are really strings, and there is an algorithm to take a number and make a string representation of it, sometimes called `itoa()`.  The reverse, taking a string that looks like a printable number to an actual number is the reverse, `atoi()`.  Compilers and assemblers routinely do this `atoi()`, since type our programs in text (think strings) but often want to manipulate the numbers represented by those strings.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to compare two bytes you need to specify size before the `[]`. For example:

```
size: dw 0x0000

cmp word[size], 0xFFFF
je ...
```

Also when adding you should do

```
add word[size], 1
```

instead of

```
add [size], word 1
```

And same with here:

```
mov [size], word 00
add [size], word '0'
```

should be

```
mov word [size], 0x0000
add word [size], '0'
```

Also, this code doesn't ensure that you loop 20 times.

```
cmp [size], word '20'
je end
```

Because `'0' + 20` isn't `'20'`. To loop 20 times you need to write:

```
cmp word [size], 0x0044
je end
```

`0x44` is `'0' + 20 = 0x30 + 20 = 0x44`

Try and let me know if the code is still broken after these changes.

Edit: Okay so here it goes:

Firstly I assume that this function gets input. You did not show the implementation.

```
; get first value
mov ecx, choosenshape 
mov edx, 1
call readthevalue
```

Also I don't know what this is

```
; take space between 
call takespaces
```

The main problem with the code is here:

```
Outputtherectangle:
    
    add word[counter], 1
    
    mov al, byte [counter]
    
    cmp al, byte [size1]
    je end
    
    mov eax,4           
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,size1     
    mov edx,2    
    int 80h 
    
    mov eax,4           
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,size2     
    mov edx,2    
    int 80h 
    
    add [counter], word '00'
    mov eax,4           
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,counter     
    mov edx,2    
    int 80h 
    
    jmp end
```

As you can see in the code you are not even looping here. Also you are not printing the correct thing. Firstly check the reference for what arguments `eax=4, int0x80` should take.

```
eax = 4 for write
ecx = message to write
ebx = file descriptor (1 for stdout)
edx = message length
```

with that in mind let's start writing our rectangle function:

I am writing the size1 and size2 here again, you can adapt this code to yourself later. We also need two counters, one to keep the row count and one to keep the column count.

```
section .data

size1: dw 0x5
size2: dw 0x10
counter1: dw 0x0000
counter2: dw 0x0000 
star: db '*'
newline: db 0x0a

section .text

Outputtherectangle:
    mov word [counter1], 0 ; reset counter
    
.loop1:
    mov word [counter2], 0 ; start loop and reset counter
    mov ax, word [size1] 
    cmp word [counter1], ax ; check if we are at the end of loop
    jge endRectangle ; if we are end the function

.loop2:
    mov ax, word[size2]
    cmp word [counter2], ax ; start the second loop
    jge .loop2end

    mov eax, 4 ; write
    mov ecx, star ; star's address
    mov ebx, 1 ; to stdout
    mov edx, 1 ; msg length is 1
    int 0x80 ; write

    add word [counter2], 1 ; add row count
    jmp .loop2 ; loop

.loop2end:

    mov eax, 4 ; write
    mov ecx, newline ; newline's address
    mov ebx, 1 ; to stdout
    mov edx, 1 ; msg length is 1
    int 0x80 ; write

    add word [counter1], 1 ; add column count
    jmp .loop1 ; loop

endRectangle:
    ret ; or do something else
```

If you run this code you get the following output

```
****************
****************
****************
****************
****************
```

Comment: @Noelle472 could you elaborate? What kind of output are you getting?

Comment: it does work but im trying to apply this logic to another project where i need to draw a sqaure of * depending on user input of length and width so that it would print * until the length and widith are met.

Comment: @Noelle472 does the code I post work as expected? If it does I will help you with the square

Comment: Yes it works but when I try to apply it to my project it doesnt work

Comment: @Noelle472 please put your real code as an edit. I cannot help without seeing the code

Comment: I updated the code. I'm getting the user input right, I just can't figure out how to loop it the amount of times the user inputs and compare the 2 values to print of the correct number of *

Comment: @Noelle472 I will format the code and see what is wrong with it. Can you give example and sample input and output

Comment: So to draw a sqaure the user would input R 04 12                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                    .     (. is first byte of the last line of user input)                                                                      The R represents that the user wants to draw a rectangle, 04 is the width, 12 is the length, and the period represents end program becuase the user can draw as many shapes as they wish until period is read.

Comment: @Noelle472 will the rectangle be 4 stars by 12 stars?

Comment: it will have 4 rows and each row has 12 stars @Özgür Güzeldereli

Comment: @Noelle472 yes okay

Comment: @Noelle472 I have added an working implementation for the ```Outputtherectangle``` function.

Comment: Thanks alot I will now try to implement this.

Comment: I tried applying user input for the dimensions but now I get an infinite loop.

Comment: @Noelle472 Could you share your ```readthevalue``` function

Comment: readthevalue:    
mov eax,3        
mov ebx,0         
int 80h              
ret            ;return back

Comment: @Noelle472 Are you sure that you are getting the input correctly. If you are typing fıor example "51" into the input you would be sending 51 as a character but you need it as a number to set size so you have to convert your input to a number